# MYSQL : Why a data of 10 536 bytes get error 1406 Data too long for a TEXT column max size of 65 535 bytes

Tags: mysql

### Introduction

I've been developping a web application for a bit more then 5 years and I never goes deep into mysql. For some days, I've been digging deeper to make my tables more efficient. I found a table that got 2 LONGTEXT column and one have a field that is filled approximately 10% of the times (1194 / 14229). I took the decision to create another table that will contain that field and a foreign key to the other table and drop that column.

First step I did was to check the maximum value of that current column to see if LONGTEXT was needed.
`SELECT MAX(payload) AS 'Maximum Value' FROM v3_lead_notes;` The result was a value with `Data Length: 10536 bytes`.

According to some search on google, I found this: [Understanding Storage Sizes for MySQL TEXT Data Types](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/understanding-strorage-sizes-for-mysql-text-data-types/)

So I set the new payload column at TEXT instead of LONGTEXT. That because from my understanding, MySQL will reserve empty space for the LONGTEXT field even if it's set to null and this result on larger table size then what we actually need.

### Problem

I tried running that script:

```
    $notes = V3LeadNote::withTrashed()->where('payload', '!=', null)->get();
    $this->info(PHP_EOL.'Modifying  '.$notes->count().' notes.');
    $bar = $this->output->createProgressBar($notes->count());
    foreach ($notes as $note) {
        $payload = new V3LeadNotePayload;
        $payload->lead_note_id = $note->id;
        $payload->payload = $note->payload;
        $payload->save();
        $bar->advance();
    }
    $bar->finish();
    $this->info(PHP_EOL.'Done.'.PHP_EOL);
```

And got that error: `String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'payload' at row 1")`

**How could the data be too long if the the maximum one is 10 536 bytes and the max size for TEXT column is 65 535 bytes ?**

### Specifications

MySQL 5.7
Engine: InnoDB
Encoding: utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: I used MySQL Workbench, right click on the value then open Value in the viewer. At the bottom, it show the Data Length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MAX(payload)` won't find the longest payload. Strings are compared lexicographically, so `z` is higher than `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` even though it's shorter.

If you want to find the maximum length, use

```
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(payload)) AS `Maximum Length` FROM v3_lead_notes;
```

If you want to see what that long payload is, you can do:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(payload, 1, 100)
FROM v3_lead_notes
ORDER BY LENGTH(payload) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. The longest data is in fact 107 916 628 bytes. Now I see why I can't use TEXT column type.

Comment: yeah, that's a little too long